# Qt5 : Get value of item clicked in a listview

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a Qt5.7 application where I am populating a `QListView` after reading stuff from a file. Here's the exact code of it.

```
QStringListModel *model;
model = new QStringListModel(this);
model->setStringList(stringList); //stringList has a list of strings
ui->listView->setModel(model);
ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers); //To disable editing
```

Now this displays the list just fine in a `QListView` that I have set up. What I need to do now is to get the string that has been double clicked and use that value elsewhere. How do I achieve that?
What I tried doing was to attach a listener to the `QListView` this way

```
... // the rest of the code
connect(ui->listView, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(fetch()));
...
```

And then I have the function `fetch`

```
void Window::fetch () {
  qDebug() << "Something was clicked!";
  QObject *s = sender();
  qDebug() << s->objectName();
}
```

However the `objectName()` function returns "listView" and not the listView item or the index.

Comment: You should add a `QModelIndex` as parameter to your slot and work with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal already provides you with a `QModelIndex` which was clicked.

So you should change your slot to this:

```
void Window::fetch (QModelIndex index)
{
....
```

`QModelIndex` has now a column and a row property. Because a list has no columns you are interessted in the row. This is the index of the item clicked.

```
//get model and cast to QStringListModel
QStringListModel* listModel= qobject_cast<QStringListModel*>(ui->listView->model());
//get value at row()
QString value = listModel->stringList().at(index.row());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the index as parameter of your slot. You can use that index to access the list

Your code should be some thing like this.

`void Window::fetch (QModelIndex index) {
    /* Do some thing you want to do*/
}`